# Angular 2 Reactive form make both select dropdowns required if one has had one of its options selected

Tags: angular

I have 2 select dropdowns. Both are optional fields. However I need them both to be required if one of those two has had one of its options selected. I'm looking everywhere and I know this would be a custom validator but I have no idea where to begin as all the examples online don't come close to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume if you enter pin , confirmpin is must (*vice versa*) else no need of required validations for both.

Code:

```
this.UserForm = this.fb.group({
       ....
       ....
        security: this.fb.group({
            pin: [this.securityobj.pin],
            confirmpin: [this.securityobj.confimrpin]
        }, {validator: abhimatcher})

    });
```

customValidator

```
export const customValidator= (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {
    const initalText = control.get('pin');
    const requiredText = control.get('confirmpin');

    if (initalText || requiredText)
        return null;

    else
        return { customValidate: true }; 
 }
```

html

```
       <form [formGroup]="UserForm"  novalidate  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(UserForm)">
           .....
           .....
            <input type="password" class="form-group" formControlName="pin">
                            <div *ngIf="UserForm.get('security').hasError('customValidate') && UserForm.get('security').get('pin').touched" class="text-danger">
                                pin is required!
                            </div>
                        </div><br />
                        <div>
                            <label class="center-block">ConfirmPin:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-group" formControlName="confirmpin">
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="UserForm.get('security').hasError('customValidate') && UserForm.get('security').get('confirmpin').touched" class="text-danger">
                            pin is required!
                        </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="UserForm.invalid">Submit</button>
 </form>
```